# Python: Parse string "30DEC05" to datetime

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, time

I have a strings formatted like "30DEC05" which in this example would represent December 30, 2005.  How can I parse this string to a datetime?

Comment: Oddly enough, your example works without error for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('30DEC05', '%d%b%y')
datetime.datetime(2005, 12, 30, 0, 0)
```

Note: `%b` depends on your locale.